# How to get value of attribute of changed input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have two input fields with the same class `sliderValue`, with `data-index=0` and `data-index=1`:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <input type="text" class="sliderValue" data-index="0" value="5"/>
    <input type="text" class="sliderValue" data-index="1" value="10"/>
    <a id="submit_price" href="some_url" class="btn btn-default">OK</a>
</div>
```

How can I get the value of `data-index` once the value of the field is changed? To be simple: I would like to know which field (1st or 2nd) is changed.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input.sliderValue").change(function() {

            var dataIndex = ???;

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.data` method:

```
var dataIndex = $(this).data("index");
```

Answer (score 1):

Or for the vanilla JS / JQuery hybrid (just because..).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.sliderValue").change(function(e) {
        var el = e.currentTarget;
        var dataIndex = el.getAttribute('data-index');
    });
});
```

You should probably accept someone else's answer as it's more geared to JQuery, this was just to show.